# Getting AD Group's creation timestamp

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, active-directory-group

How do I get the creation timestamp of an AD Group ?

I looked at IGroupCollection but couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK , we can't get the creation timestamp of an AD Group with Azure AD REST API or client library , since no creation timestamp property exists in [Group Entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#group-entity) . If you want to get the creation timestamp property with rest api , you could post a feedback in [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) .

Comment: The reason I want to know the timestamp is, when i get webapi request to create a group, i check if it already exists. But some times it takes few minutes after the group is created for it to be available in the Group list. So if i get multiple requests within seconds for the same group, it creates multiple groups of the same name.

Comment: @Tany, multiple requests should be controlled with your own code , you need to catch the successful response of create group api , avoid send multiple requests .

Comment: @nan-yu-msft I get successful response of create group api. But for subsequent calls, I go and check in Groups Collection of the AD library. It takes few minutes for the new group to reflect in the collection.